# Read 16 bytes from Modbus Equipment

Tags: c, byte, case, bit, modbus

I have a problem related to a Modbus equipment. I am trying to read some Modbus registers but i am stuck in some reading problems.

I am using the code below to read bit by bit but i need to read 2 bytes (16 bites) from one reading and i would need some help to add a new case for that specific reading.

```
        case 1:     // 1Bit
            fData[Data_Struct[nLoop].nChanel] = (float)
                ( ( Frame[Data_Struct[nLoop].nOffset]
                    >> Data_Struct[nLoop].nScaleBit ) & 0x01 );
            break;
```

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: How does it make sense to have a float with value 0 or 1?

Comment: the code lines from above were written by someone else and i only need to add a new case to the project. i share the same opinion but it seems that it is working and i left it like this

Comment: float* fData, (fData function is waiting for a float)